# How to add Calculated rows in a PBI Matrix

Tags: powerbi

i want to insert calculated rows to a power BI matrix. How do i add this?

i can add calculated columns. But not sure how to structure the data and what are the functions to use to do this

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please paste some codes and elaborate where the problem is?

Comment: i havent used any code. Just not sure how add a code to a row in this. i can add calculated measures or columns to this matrix. But where i face a problem is, how to put these to rows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Abdul. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask